# script doesn't work if i put an exit code in it

Tags: linux, bash, nagios

There is a part of my script:

```
x=`grep -i -o -P '.{0,28}BACKUP TO NASBACKUP stopped.' /var/log/nascad.log`  
if [[ $x == *"BACKUP TO NASBACKUP stopped."* ]]  
    then  
    echo "Backup Stopped!Something Wrong.." "$x"  
    echo -n "" > /var/log/nascad.log  
    exit 2  
else  
    echo "All ok"  
    exit 0  
fi
```

with exit code the `echo -n "" > /var/log/nascad.log` command doesn't work, it is as if it were not executed.
Without it all works.

It's a `nagios` script, so I need the exit code.  And if I launch it by hand, it works.  When is executed from nagios it doesn't work.

Comment: `command doesn't work` - You mean the file is not empty? What is the error code you are getting in that case?

Comment: Are you expecting the script to return error-code as `2` and not seeing it? Please elaborate your question more

Comment: thanks, edited the original question.

Comment: `echo -n ""` doesn't write anything; it outputs an empty string with no trailing newline. The only effect that line can have is to create `/var/log/nascad.log` if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: @damned: it doesn't make sense to me, you are checking for a string in the `/var/log/nascad.log`. Assuming the string is present, you are nullifying the file using `    echo -n "" > /var/log/nascad.log ` and returning an error code 2 which is you are likely to get. In case the string is not there, you will get an error code `0`. What error codes are you checking against or what is your assert condition?

Comment: What are you expecting the "echo -n" line to do? What condition to you expect nascad.log to be in afterwards?

Comment: ok, this is the full story: when nas1 start, finish or has errors with the replica to nas2, write a log in my nagios box with syslog in /vat/log/nascad.log   I analyze this log with grep, and do some messaging with this result, after this i want to empty the log file with the echo - n command so i can interprete the next log written send by the nas replica process.

Comment: The biggest difference you'll most likely have between running it from command line and running it from nagios is the shell running it (add `#!/bin/bash`) and the PATH being used.  I don't think the latter is an issue with the commands you are using.  Add your shbang in and try again.

Comment: it's seems to work..that surprise me because i had already tried this on my one of 100 attempts..probably i made a lot of confusion..i will do some more test asap..thanks for now!

Comment: (`if … then … exit ; else … fi` ← the `else` is superfluous.)

Comment: still not work..it's ok if i launch the script by hand but partially works when integrated in nagiosxi..it doesn't empty the log file..time to contact nagios support batman!

Comment: `echo -n "" >file` is more idiomatically written `>file`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a permission problem. Personally, when I want to try a homemade script with nagios, I launch the script by hand as the nagios user :

```
su - nagios -s /bin/bash
./your_script
```

If it's a permission issue (for the log file), you have to change the owner of this script to the nagios user :

```
chown nagios /var/log/nascad.log
```

Tell me if I'm faster than the nagiosxi support (i know how long they can be...)

-- EDIT --

I tried this perl script who is working for me. Maybe you have to adjust the regexp for your needs.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename="/var/log/nascad.log";

open(my $fh,"<",$filename);

foreach(<$fh>){
    if ($_ =~ /(.*?BACKUP TO NASBACKUP stopped.*)/i){
        print "Backup stopped! Something wrong... : $1\n";
        open($fh, ">", $filename);
        exit (2);
    }
}

print "All ok!\n";
exit (0);
```

Comment: nope, already tried with the firsts check. At last i changed my script to work with email and without exit code..damn exit code!

Comment: oww it's a real problem, a nagios plugin without an exit code is so useless... I'm going to write a similar plugin with perl just to try.

Comment: I edited my answers, you can try this script if you want.

Comment: I found what was my problem..with NagiosXi the 'test check command' button uses the user 'apache' not 'nagios'! This messed up all my permission setup!

Comment: Okay, I'm using mod_gearman then I never use the 'test check command' button. I'm glad it's working for you now !